# stop writting in a text file in standard LUA

Tags: file, lua

I want to stop writting in a text file.
my text file has 4 lines and I'm reading file, line by line, so I've got:

> apple orange banana cocoa apple orange banana cocoa apple orange
>   banana cocoa, and so on till I leave from the app.

I just want output like:

> apple 
>   orange 
>   banana 
>   cocoa

And stop, how I can get it?

I've tried a lot of different code, with not to avail.
I ignore how many lines the file has, even how many files are, since not all users has a file, ignore how many users has file, this is random, so I should to find out how many users have files, open each one's file, and check some data that I need, and that I can't publish here.
I has this solved, problem is the huge file I'm getting.

```
while i <= #g do 
   i = i + 1
   fho:write(zline)
   fho:write("\n")      
   break    
end
```

I entered all the users with files in an array, and used the size of the array as an iterator in a loop, without any positive results.
I expect to stop writting when end file being reached.

Comment: What is `g`????

Comment: 'g' is a customers with file array. I think if I have a customers with file list as an array, so I could use the array size (#g) to prevent the script copying the same again and again.

Comment: Use a (temporary) table (map) for deduplication, maps are very fast in Lua.

Comment: what is the purpose of a while loop if you have an unconditional break in its body?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example

```
local lines {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}

local file = io.open("test.txt", "a")

if file then

  for i = 1, 4 do
    file:write(lines[i] .. "\n")
  end

  file:close()

end
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of thanks guys for all your comments and suggestions.
Finally I get the file lines number and hold this value en in a var named "d" and use it as in below script:

```
for line in r2:lines() do
    if line ~= "" then
        xline = line:match( "^%s*(.-)%s*$" )
    if i <= d-2 then
        i = i + 1
        r1 = assert(io.open(fPath,"a+"))    
        io.input(r1)
        r1:write(xline .."\n")  
        r1:close()
    end

    end
end
```

and it works.

As aside note, I had used table, with the idea of use their lenght (#g)

```
for line in r2:lines() do
    if line ~= "" then
        xline = line:match( "^%s*(.-)%s*$" )
        table.insert(xlines,xline)
```

but for any reason when I had debbuged it  thru and print(#g), it don't stop to increase, like a chronometer, ignore why don't stop, when last line being readed.

@  Piglet
Your right guy, It was only a desperate attempt to achieve the goal.
Note: english no my firts lang, so apologize for my faults. :)
best reggards.